# How is a Multi Access Edge Application hosted and connected to carriers user data?

Tags: mobile-data

I understand in general the core concept behind Multi Access Edge Computing. I have read through a lots of papers and everything is "high level" conceptual architecture. But when it comes to examples, real-world examples, guidelines etc. I couldn't find anything.

As far as I understood simplified, there are virtual machines with some applications running on it. These could be, from my understanding, anything from Python scripts to C++ or everything else.

My concrete question is:

- How to get the carrier data per user and respond to it?

Did I understand correctly how it is - that the application is hosted on some virtual machine with a piece of software on it?